# How to get the longest 2 appropriate fields in oracle

Tags: oracle, maxlength

I understand how to get the longest field from one column in oracle as below:

```
select name from daTable
where length(name) =
(select max(length(name)) from daTable)
```

But now I have 2 tables: one for car_make which have a column make_description (like Nissan) and the other for car_model  which have a column model_description (like Tida). How can I get the longest field: car_make with his appropriate car_model from the 2 different tables?

This is the structure of my tables:

```
Car_make: id_make , make_description
Car_model: id_model, model description,P_id_make
```

(where P_id_make in car_model is id_make in car_make)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could  concat the column  this way

```
  select a.make_description  || ' ' || b.model_description as name 
  from Car_make a 
  INNER JOIN Car_model b on a.id_make = b.P_id_make
  where length( a.make_description  || ' ' || b.model_description  ) =
  ( select max(a.make_description  || ' ' || b.model_description) 
  from Car_make a 
  INNER JOIN Car_model b on a.id_make = b.P_id_make)
```

Comment: @H.Al   . i have update the answr  with .. join  for both table